# Problemas para conectar a servidor con SSH2 desde PHP

Tags: php, ssh

Estoy intentando conectar desde mi servidor local WAMP por `ssh2_connect()` a un servidor de ficheros y me devuelve el siguiente mensaje de error:

> ssh2_connect(): Error starting up SSH connection(-43): Failed getting banner

En cambio esta misma conexión desde el servidor Apache hacia el servidor de ficheros funciona.

He comprobado que tengo las librerías correctamente instaladas y el `php.ini` configurado y todo está bien.

He seguido la siguiente guía:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15134421/php-install-ssh2-on-windows-machine

Dos preguntas:

1. ¿Saben cuál puede ser el motivo del error?
2. No encuentro un listado de códigos de error de la librería 
   `ssh2_connect()`? En este caso me interesa saber cuál el código `-43`.

Comment: Hola Salvador, nunca está de más poner el código que estás intentando utilizar, qué error te está dando, etc. Cuanta más información, mejor

Comment: ¿Podrías indicarnos información acerca del tipo de servidor de archivos al que tratas de conectarte? ¿Es FTPS, SFTP o SCP? ¿Qué comando usas para conectarte al servidor desde el intérprete de órdenes (desde la shell)?

Comment: Buenos días @Salvador , ¿estás aún interesado en resolver este problema?

Comment: Buenos días, ya lo he resuelto. gracias